# прозрачность в Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

мне нужно чтобы кнопка была прозрачна, есть ли в kivy метод сделать это? поискал в документации к button, не нашел

Answer (score 2):

Метод `.opacity`, и он не только для кнопок.

```py
btn = Button()
btn.opacity = 0.5
```

Представленный выше код создаст кнопку с 50% прозрачности.

Answer (score 0):

```
            button = Button(text = '0',
                background_normal = 'ng.png',
                background_down = 'ng.png',
                size_hint = (.2, .1),
                pos_hint = {"x":.4, "y":.0})
```

создай прозрачный .png и поставь его в кнопку.